# UITAbleView not in alphabetical order?iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

I have a tableView with several Sections being populated from a plist of NSDictionaries

How do I have it arrange the sections in the order they are in in the NSDictionary instead of alphabetically?

Comment: You'll need to provide *some* sample code for anyone to be able to help you. How are you getting data from the plist to your table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I improvised a solution. I added a "01", "02", "03" etc to the beginning of each dictionary name then just added the code to remove those two characters before displaying it:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    key = [key substringFromIndex:2];
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NSDictionary is *unordered*. You should use an NSArray (or `std::vector`, or `std::map`, etc.) as the data source.

To get the keys, use `-allKeys`. To get a sorted array from it, use `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:`.